# How to use map.getCenter() and google.maps.event.trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, bitrix

I'm using Gmap module. If you try to initialise the map on a hidden div, then it will fail to display.

we can use `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` in the script, because I always got my map on top left corner.

I found the solution with `map.getCenter(); map.setCenter();` But when I use this in my js file inside my tabs custom code, it doesn't work, because "map" is not defined.

Is there a solution for this?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.spoiler-body1').hide(); 
        $('.spoiler-head').click(function(){

            var mapObj = window[$('.bx-google-map').attr('id')];
            var center = mapObj.getCenter();

            $(this).toggleClass("folded1").toggleClass("unfolded").next().slideToggle();

            google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, 'resize');

            mapObj.setCenter(center);
        });
    });
```

Comment: where is the code for map initialization and where is positioned in the HTML doc?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have the map initialize on a separate `window.onload` (or equivalent). This script needs to be run *after* the map initialization. What is happening now is that *this* `window.onload` runs slightly before the other one with the initialization script, even though they technically fire at the same time.

This can be fixed by appending this script to the map initialization directly. This would guarantee that the timing lines up.